# Rspec: Carrierwave doesn't save file from spec/fixtures

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave

I have my `Report` model:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :ready_status, :document

  mount_uploader :document, DocumentUploader

  def attach( report_file )
    self.update_attributes( :document => File.open( report_file ), :ready_status => true )
  end
end
```

This model has `attach` metod, which i use to save document and other param. Now i want to test that this function works.

**/spec/models/report_spec.rb**

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'spec_helper'

describe Report do
  before(:each) do
    @user = User.make!
  end

  ...

  context "File's saving" do
    before(:each) do
      @report = @user.reports.create
      @csv_report_file = "#{Rails.root}/spec/files/report.csv"
    end

    it "CSV should be saved" do
      csv_report_filename = @csv_report_file.split("/").last

      @report.attach @csv_report_file
      @report.reload

      @report.document.file.filename.should == csv_report_filename
    end
  end
end
```

When i try to saving file from `/spec/files` i get such error:

```
Report File's saving CSV should be saved
     Failure/Error: @report.document.file.filename.should == csv_report_filename
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `filename' for nil:NilClass
```

But when i try another file from another folder (for example `"#{Rails.root}/samples/my-report.csv"`) then my test passes.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, i found the answer. Carrierwave doesn't save empty file and i had one. When i added some data in the file (`/spec/files/report.csv`) my problem has gone.